# rendering canvas in firefox not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, data-url

I'm trying to convert a image to base64 url with canvas :

```
      var canv = document.createElement('canvas');      
      var ctx = canv.getContext("2d",{preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
      canv.width = img.width;
      canv.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      result = canv.toDataURL("image/jpeg", quality);
```

works 100% of the time in chrome, but in firefox results in empty and contains only "data:" 1 time out of 3 (30% of the time)

Equally if I try :

```
      $(body).append(canv);
```

no image is displayed in the canvas.

I have been advised to add {preserveDrawingBuffer: true} but it doesn't help.

To provide more context this operation are executed async and might be rendering several different canvas at the same time, i thought that might have something to do with it.

This must be a known issue, does anyone one has any clue about it ?

Comment: Is your image loaded?  You probably have to put a callback on img.  If it is working 100% of the time in Chrome, it is likely that it is just cached there for you.

Comment: use  $('body').append(canv);